# Where can I find information about the company reference letter requirement for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indonesian-citizens

I am planning to visit Europe this year and confused about Company reference letter requirement for Schengen visa.

For example, This is what I found in [Netherland Embassy website](http://singapore.nlembassy.org/Products_and_Services/Consular_services/Visa/Visas_for_the_Netherlands_Schengen_Visas/Applying_for_a_Schengen_visa)

- "documents showing that you intend to return to your country of origin (such as an employer’s declaration or the deeds to your home)"

Which I feel is not really clear. Where can I find complete, detail information about what need to be written in this letter?

Comment: Am I right you are from Singapore?

Comment: I'm from Indonesia.

Comment: Don't expect anything clear or consistent from the Dutch bureaucracy. Don't ever assume, that what you hear from Dutch clerk is correct. If you'll be also visiting other countries, you'd be much better of applying in some the other country embassy (unless it's Belgium, in which case it isn't much better).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, where are you going? You want to visit the one country or some number of them? You should note, that there is no such thing like **Schengen** visa. You can only get visa to the country **in Schengen**. So, first of all, you must select the one country **you will be most time in**. Note that different countries have their own requirements to the tourists.
And since you're in Schengen, you can easily travel between countries in it without any problems.

According to your question, there are a lot of types of the *documents showing that you intend to return to your country of origin*:

1. If you have a good job, simply get the receipt from your bank account showing that you are not going to search the job in Schengen.
2. If you have family, get some documents about that - there are much more chances that you will return to your home for your family.
3. If you have any immovables, provide documents about it.
4. Ask for a list in the embassy of the country you have chosen - there can be some more documents that count as guarantee for you to return home.

Comment: I will go to 5 countries starting in Netherland, end in Paris.

Comment: @Rudy What country will you stay for the most time?

Comment: actually Germany ( 2 days ). But the germany embassy queue for visa is very long. Can I try the first country that I will set my foot on? ( Aka  Netherland )

Comment: As I've said, you must select the one country you will be most time in. You can try to cheat, and try to get visa at the embassy of the country you'll be at first time, but it could make troubles for you in future.

Answer (score 4):

As VMAtm already mentioned, there are various ways to ensure that you will return home after your vacation.

I just want to add a useful resource a friend of mine also used when applying for a Visa.

http://www.travellerspoint.com/guide/Schengen_Visa/

Answer (score 2):

Found and use this.

http://www.travelvisapro.com/?funct,do.html,url.business_letter_for_visa